# OOP For Loop SQL Update Query Quantity

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I am trying to create a query inside of my FOR LOOP that will update my products Quantity column. When a customer checks out they create a row in my orders table, from there a row is created in orderdetails for every item purchased.

I have three tables with the following columns

1. products (ID, Quantity)
2. orderdetails (ID, OrderID, ProductID, Quantity) "OrderID and ProductID are foreign keys"
3. orders  (ID)

The error I am receiving is

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on
>   boolean

```
$newOrder = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (UserID, Amount) Values ('{$_SESSION['u_id']}','{$_SESSION['$s']}')");
$newOrder->execute();
$ordersid = $newOrder->insert_id;   

//Save order details for new order
$cart = json_decode(json_encode($_SESSION['cart']));
//For loop with query that creates a new row for every item
for($i = 0; $i<count($cart); $i++){
    $new_Orderdetail = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `orderdetails` (`OrderID`,`ProductID`,`Price`,`Quantity`) VALUES(".$ordersid.",".$cart[$i]->id.",".$cart[$i]->price.",".$cart[$i]->quantity.")");
    $new_Orderdetail->execute();
    $new_Orderdetailid = $new_Orderdetail->insert_id;
    echo "$new_Orderdetailid </br>";
    $update = $conn->prepare("Update p SET Quantity = Quantity - ".$cart[$i]->quantity." FROM products p where ID = ".$cart[$i]->id"");
    $update->execute();
}
```

Can someone please help me solve why I am receiving this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I see the field `Quantity` in table `products` is of type `VARCHAR()` so you must use `''` to add the value.

EDIT: Since you now want the field to be of type `INT`, the `''` are no longer required. I've update the code:

```
// Corrected code
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE products SET Quantity=".$cart[$i]->quantity." WHERE ID=".$cart[$i]->id);
```

And you had two `""` without a dot at the end of the same statement, and by the way the `""` aren't needed here if `$cart[$i]->id` is `numeric`:

```
// Sample from your code
FROM products p where ID = ".$cart[$i]->id"");

// Corrected to
FROM products p where ID=".$cart[$i]->id);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and knowledge, this has solved my error message but now my query deletes all the quantity from the specified product table row. Feels sad man

Comment: Hmm.. Can you double check that the column `Quantity` in table `products` is `VARCHAR` and not for example `INT`?

Comment: Maybe that was a typo and it should have been an `int`. Try this: `$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE products SET Quantity=".$cart[$i]->quantity." WHERE ID=".$cart[$i]->id);`

Comment: It is actually an INT should I change it to VARCHAR?

Comment: If you want the output for example `Quantity - 5` in your column then you should change to VARCHAR but if just a number is Ok then leave it at `INT` and I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ya I would prefer if it stayed as a number.